# How can I satisfy borrow checker when implementing a cache?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a cache type that stores entries of type `CacheEntry<T>`. I was hoping to store the entries in a vector, but also have a `HashMap` for quicker lookup:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Key {
    // ...
}

pub struct CacheEntry<T> {
    pub key: Key,
    pub data: T,
}

pub struct Cache<T> {
    pub entries: Vec<CacheEntry<T>>,
    pub entry_map: HashMap<Key, CacheEntry<T>>,
}

impl<T> Cache<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Cache<T> {
        let entries: Vec<CacheEntry<T>> = vec![];
        let entry_map: HashMap<Key, CacheEntry<T>> = HashMap::new();

        Cache {
            entries,
            entry_map,
        }
    }

    pub fn add_entry(&mut self, entry: CacheEntry<T>) {
        self.entries.push(entry);
        self.entry_map.insert(entry.key, entry);
    }
}
```

I'm having some trouble with the `add_entry` method:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `entry.key`
  --> src\cache_test.rs:31:31
   |
29 |     pub fn add_entry(&mut self, entry: CacheEntry<T>) {
   |                                 ----- move occurs because `entry` has type `CacheEntry<T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
30 |         self.entries.push(entry);
   |                           ----- value moved here
31 |         self.entry_map.insert(entry.key, entry);
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

The error message is clear, and I understand with Rust's hashmap implementation, the hashmap has to "own" the key. I'm not sure how to get around this, though.

I tried making the hashmap store references instead:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Key {
    // ...
}

pub struct CacheEntry<T> {
    pub key: Key,
    pub data: T,
}

pub struct Cache<'a, T> {
    pub entries: Vec<CacheEntry<T>>,
    pub entry_map: HashMap<&'a Key, &'a CacheEntry<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Cache<'a, T> {
    pub fn new() -> Cache<'a, T> {
        let entries: Vec<CacheEntry<T>> = vec![];
        let entry_map: HashMap<&Key, &CacheEntry<T>> = HashMap::new();

        Cache {
            entries,
            entry_map,
        }
    }

    pub fn add_entry(&mut self, entry: CacheEntry<T>) {
        self.entries.push(entry);
        self.entry_map.insert(&entry.key, &entry);
    }
}
```

However, now I get an error saying the reference does not live long enough:

```
error[E0597]: `entry.key` does not live long enough
  --> src\cache_test.rs:31:31
   |
18 | impl<'a, T> Cache<'a, T> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
31 |         self.entry_map.insert(&entry.key, &entry);
   |         ----------------------^^^^^^^^^^---------
   |         |                     |
   |         |                     borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `entry.key` is borrowed for `'a`
32 |     }
   |     - `entry.key` dropped here while still borrowed
```

This also makes sense, but again I'm not sure how best to get around it.

What I would like is for the `Cache` struct to "own" the cache entry after insert, and to have the entries available as a vector, but still have the hashmap for quick lookup by key. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) that we can use?

Comment: Here is a playground I just created:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=00b1f94ac8ffb2b439a07714d9f80807

Comment: Why not just store the entries directly in the `HashMap`? If you have to have both Vec and Map, try wrapping each `CacheEntry` in an `Rc` in the Vector and cloning it into the HashMap.

Comment: Yeah I'm curious what the purpose behind the `Vec` is as well. You should probably choose one or the other. Or you could change it to map key to index in the vector.

Comment: [playground storing index into Vec](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b96cbcec741bd83c16751212024aa06a)

Comment: Oh interesting, hadn't occurred to me to just store the index in the hash map - thanks @PitaJ!